# Is $Q[x,y]/x^2+y^2-1$ principal ideal domain?

Tags: ring-theory

I want to know whether $Q[x,\sqrt{1-x^2}]$ is PID or not.

By using ring homomorphism theorem,
I just need to know whether $Q[x,y]/x^2+y^2-1$ is PID or not.

I guess $x,y/x^2+y^2-1$ is not PID but I cannot formally prove this.

Thank you in advance!

And I heard a difficult answer.

'$Q[x,y]/x^2+y^2-1$ is Dedekind domain and it's Picard group is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, so $Q[x,y]/x^2+y^2-1$ is not PID'.

If there is a more detailed explanation of this answer, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ideal $(X,Y)$ in the quotient. Intuitively, we can expect that this ideal is not principal because we only have the relation $X^2+Y^2=1$ and this does not allow us to eliminate one of the variables $X,Y$ in this ideal as generator. Now, try to formally prove this!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your intuitively answer is very helpful and I will continue to think about it. I may comment few days later if I could generate steps. Thank you very much!

Comment: I tried but I couldn't... If you are OK, I'm happy if you could show answer here. Sorry and thank you so much for taking care of me..

Comment: Thank you so much despite being busy!. I'm looking forward to the answer.